Inverse of Sparse Binary Matrix (of size $n$) is dependent on $n$ mod $4$
Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $$ A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 &  0& 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & ... & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So to reiterate, it is a traceless symmetric matrix. All entries are $0$ except for: above and below the diagonals, and the top right and bottom left corner.
The objective is to find $A^{-1}$. I've done this numerically and convinced myself of the answer.
However, what's interesting is $A^{-1}$ changes form depending on the value of ($n$ mod $4$).
Case 0: ($n$ mod $4 = 0$)
In this case $A$ is singular.
Case 1: ($n$ mod $4 = 1$)
For $n=5$
$$
A^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
As $n$ goes higher, the $(\tfrac 1 2 , \tfrac 1 2, - \tfrac 1 2, - \tfrac 1 2)$ in the top row repeats, as well as the bottom row etc.
Case 2: ($n$ mod $4 = 2$)
For $n = 6$
$$
A^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and the pattern continues
Case 3: ($n$ mod $4$ = 3)
This is just the negative of case 2

My question is, why does the behavior change depending on the value of $n$ mod $4$?
There has to be some group $\mathbb Z_4$ structure occurring. Perhaps the answer I'm looking for is "oh the structure of the matrix / this pattern does this, which is a rep of $\mathbb Z_4$".

I've attached Mathematica code below if you'd like to explore other $n$
m = 2; 
modEq = 2; (*Select what you want n mod 4 to be*)
p = 4 * m - modEq;
A = SparseArray[Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, {p, p}, 0] + 
   SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, {p, p}, 0] + 
   SparseArray[{{1, p}, {p, 1}} -> 1, {p, p}, 0];

A // MatrixForm
Inverse[A] // MatrixForm
```


$A$ is a circulant matrix, so it is diagonalized by a discrete Fourier matrix. This can help you derive under what conditions it is invertible and the inverse. Of course, you will need some knowledge of complex numbers to do this. Alternatively, you might want to permute the rows and columns so that all the indices congruent to $0 \pmod{4}$ are grouped together, and similarly for $1,2,3 \pmod{4}$. Then, you'll have a $4x4$ block matrix, where each block is roughly of size $n/4 \times n/4$.
